# What steps are necessary to migrate a Django application within the same cPanel?

Tags: python, django, migration

I have existing Python and Django Application hosted in cPanel, need to move application from one domain to another domain. in same cPanel. what are we need to change,  example [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) to [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)

Need information how to move the application.